# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when i add font aweasome to my fxml file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, font-awesome, fxml

I am trying to make a sign up page 
I have added font awesome jar file as a library to the scene builder 8.5.0 as you see[image]

I have added this as external library to the intellij IDEA 
[image]

and fxml file looks fine in both scenebuilder [image]

and integrated scenebuilder to intellij IDEA
[image]
however when I compile the code it gives this error and if I delete the fontAweasome icons it runs just fine

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=48063:E:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\reza\Desktop\medic\out\production\medic;C:\Users\reza\Desktop\medic\src\jar_files (1)\controlsfx-8.40.11.jar;C:\Users\reza\Desktop\fontawesomefx-8.9.jar;C:\Users\reza\Desktop\medic\src\fontAweasome\fontawesomefx-8.9.jar;C:\Users\reza\Desktop\medic\src\charm glisten 4.4.4\charm-glisten-4.4.4.jar;C:\Users\reza\Desktop\medic\src\charm 6.6.6\charm-glisten-6.0.0.jar" sample.Main
sign up check
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3589)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8300(Scene.java:3517)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3885)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/parser/CSSParser
    at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.<clinit>(GlyphIcon.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:560)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.Controller.SignupClicked(Controller.java:49)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 62 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Try using JavaFX 8 or using a newer version of FontAwesomeFX (i.e. one built for JavaFX 9+), in which case you may need to upgrade Scene Builder as well.

Comment: I agree that it is most likely a problem with compiling vs one JDK and running with another. Intellijs internal runtime might be different from the one from the project JDK. Which JDK are you using for the project (in the project settings)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is caused because jdk and this version of font Awesome aren't compatible 
so I have downgraded from jdk 10 to jdk 1.8
or  as @Slaw said you should upgrade your font awesome.

Comment: please put a bit more effort into wording your answer - even with not being a native speaker, word duplication (_or_) and incomplete words (_u_) should not appear in a good answer ;)

Comment: @kleopatra   I apologize for the inconvenience; I will try my best for it not to happen again.